# Dropwizard RequestLog

Tags: exception, logging, dropwizard

I have an strange exception while integration testing my Dropwizard 0.9.2 service. The exception and configuration are below.

I dont understand why requestLog is unknown? The [DW documentation](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/configuration.html#request-log) say, that below configuration part should work. The requestLog can be found in

> *io.dropwizard.server.AbstractServerFactory.class*

and

> *io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory.class*

extends it, so it should be possible to use the requestLog. Whats wrong here?

Someone knows this problem already?

**Configuration Part**

```
server:
  requestLog:
    timeZone: UTC
    appenders:
     - type: console
       threshold: DEBUG
     - type: file
       currentLogFilename: ./log/access.log
       threshold: ALL
       archive: true
       archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./log/access.%d.log.gz
       archivedFileCount: 14
  maxThreads: 1024
  minThreads: 8
  maxQueuedRequests: 1024
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 80
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 12345
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException: myService.yml has an error:
  * Unrecognized field at: server.requestLog
    Did you mean?:
      - adminConnectors
      - adminContextPath
      - adminMaxThreads
      - adminMinThreads
      - applicationConnectors
        [1 more]

    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.DropwizardTestSupport.startIfRequired(DropwizardTestSupport.java:214)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.DropwizardTestSupport.before(DropwizardTestSupport.java:115)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.junit.DropwizardAppRule.before(DropwizardAppRule.java:87)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:46)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException: myservice.yml has an error:
  * Unrecognized field at: server.requestLog
    Did you mean?:
      - adminConnectors
      - adminContextPath
      - adminMaxThreads
      - adminMinThreads
      - applicationConnectors
        [1 more]

    at io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationParsingException$Builder.build(ConfigurationParsingException.java:271)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationFactory.build(ConfigurationFactory.java:163)
    at io.dropwizard.configuration.ConfigurationFactory.build(ConfigurationFactory.java:95)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:115)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:64)
    at io.dropwizard.testing.DropwizardTestSupport.startIfRequired(DropwizardTestSupport.java:212)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "requestLog" (class io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory), not marked as ignorable (6 known properties: "adminMaxThreads", "adminConnectors", "applicationConnectors", "applicationContextPath", "adminMinThreads", "adminContextPath"])
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: .....
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using for testing as well.

Comment: This works for me. My guess is that something is wrong with the version you are using. Maybe you have an older version of DW in classpath?

Comment: Its working, but if I use the Integration Testing TestRule, then it fails.

Comment: This also happens if I create and run the the jar. Any ideas how to solve this? Is the server factory class not loaded or the wrong one? How can I check this?

Comment: Setting server type to default solves this problem but now I have some validation exceptions during start ...

Comment: could you tell me how to use the RequestLog? could you show me a demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we had the same issue. It was a problem of using an older version of Jackson. We'Ve upgraded from v `2.6.3` to v `2.6.5` and the error was gone.

Comment: Works also for upgrades from 2.7.0 to 2.7.3

Answer (score 1):

Try to put *timeZone: UTC* under each appender like this:

```
server:
  requestLog:
    appenders:
     - type: console
       threshold: DEBUG
       timeZone: UTC
     - type: file
       currentLogFilename: ./log/access.log
       threshold: ALL
       archive: true
       archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./log/access.%d.log.gz
       archivedFileCount: 14
       timeZone: UTC
  maxThreads: 1024
  minThreads: 8
  maxQueuedRequests: 1024
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 80
  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 12345
```

Answer (score 0):

The same error arose for me with more recent versions of jackson, when I added a dependency that pulled in `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.7.2`

Excluding `jackson-databind` from that dependency in pom.xml resolved it.