# Logging configuration for dropwizard to log everything into one file with custom log format

Tags: logback, dropwizard

I'm using dropwizard 0.9.2 and had to [upgrade jackson to 2.7.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35018222/194609) to make the following configuration at least starting:

```
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8080

  adminConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: 8081

  requestLog:
    timeZone: UTC
    appenders:
      - type: console  
        logFormat: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
      - type: file
        currentLogFilename: ./logs/vrp-app.log
        archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/vrp-app.%d.log.gz
        logFormat: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"

logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    "org.hibernate":
      level: DEBUG
  appenders:
    - type: console
      timeZone: UTC
      logFormat: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    - type: file
      timeZone: UTC
      currentLogFilename: ./logs/vrp-app.log
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: ./logs/vrp-app.%d.log.gz
      archivedFileCount: 5
      logFormat: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
```

But still the log format of the request log is different than the rest:

```
15:46:42.717 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @3751ms
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jun/2016:13:46:48 +0000] "GET /users HTTP/1.1" 415 56 "-" "curl/7.35.0" 136
```

Just keeping the "-type" lines in the hope that the config is picked from the `logging` section also does not work.

**What am I doing wrong?**

This should work according to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/BTdBW5XF0yc)

And is it okay to specify the same log for request log and 'normal log'. Why is this separated at all?

Answer (score 1):

requestLog logFormat is not implemented for 0.9.2. You have to move to 1.0.0-rc3 (latest) dropwizard version.

And the formatting is bit different as specified in http://logback.qos.ch/access.html

more ref: https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/apache-logging-basics/

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if it is allowed to specify two identical files or will something mess up due to this?