# How to log HTTP requests in file in Dropwizard?

Tags: java, logging, yaml, dropwizard

I'm having issue in my Dropwizard (**version 1.3.8**) app logging HTTP Requests into file. I've followed Dropwizard's [documentation](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/release-1.3.x/manual/configuration.html#file) for configuration of YAML file and my `config.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
logging:
  level: INFO
  loggers:
    com.nikolas.master_thesis: DEBUG

  appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: /home/nikola/Documents/DWApp-LOGs/DW-Bookshop_LOG.log
      threshold: ALL
      queueSize: 512
      archive: true
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /home/nikola/Documents/DWApp-LOGs/DW-Bookshop_LOG-%d.log
      archivedFileCount: 5
      timeZone: UTC
      logFormat: "%-5p [%d{ISO8601,UTC}] %c: %m%n%rEx"
      # logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined
#      logFormat: “%h %l %u %t “%r“ %s %b “%{Referer}i“ “%{User-Agent}i““ combined
#      logFormat: '%h %l %u %t '%r' %\\>s %b '%{Referer}i' '%{User-Agent}i''
#      logFormat: "%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %com.nikolas.master_thesis.examples.`config-kt`.logger{36} - %msg%n"
#      logFormat: “%h %l %u %t “%r“ %s %b “%{Referer}i“ “%{User-Agent}i““
#      logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %O \"%{Referer}i\""
#      logFormat: “%h %l %u %t “%r“ %\\>s %b “%{Referer}i“ “%{User-Agent}i““
#      logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" \"%>s\" %O \"%{Referer}i\""
#      logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
#      logFormat: combined
#      logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" /etc/httpd
#      logFormat: “%h %l %u %t “%r” %s %b “%{User-Agent}i””
#      logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" /etc/httpd
#      logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"
#        logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""
      bufferSize: 8KB
      immediateFlush: true
      # filterFactories:
      #   - type: URI
    
    - type: console
      threshold: ALL
      queueSize: 512
      discardingThreshold: 0
      timeZone: UTC
      target: stdout
      logFormat: "%-5p [%d{ISO8601,UTC}] %c: %m%n%rEx"
```

The thing is that HTTP Request is logged in console like this:

```
192.168.1.5 - - [09/Aug/2020:10:08:05 +0000] "GET /api/orders HTTP/1.1" 200 14094 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/1.8.0_161)" 710
```

...and I want to log it also in file, but it does NOT log it at all! I've tried to use commented `logFormat`s, but I get error for each of those commented `logFormat` values.
E.g. for `logFormat: "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"` when I run it in terminal (I'm using **RMI parameters to collect JMX samples from remote machine**):

`java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1616  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -jar ./target/DW-Bookshop-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar server config.yml`

...I get NumberFormatException:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ">"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.FormatInfo.valueOf(FormatInfo.java:73)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.T(Parser.java:136)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:96)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.Eopt(Parser.java:115)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.E(Parser.java:100)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:91)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.PatternLayoutBase.start(PatternLayoutBase.java:83)
    at io.dropwizard.logging.AbstractAppenderFactory.buildLayout(AbstractAppenderFactory.java:243)
    at io.dropwizard.logging.AbstractOutputStreamAppenderFactory.build(AbstractOutputStreamAppenderFactory.java:25)
    at io.dropwizard.logging.DefaultLoggingFactory.configure(DefaultLoggingFactory.java:143)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:83)
    at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
    at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
    at com.nikolas.master_thesis.DropwizardMasterThesisApplication.main(DropwizardMasterThesisApplication.java:35)
```

I've also looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37822664/6805866) answer, but no luck! Also, I'm running Fedora 31 OS and I'm using Java 8.

Any advice/help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE1:**
I've digged bit deeper into Configuration Docs and found pattern under [this](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord) link and edited value under **logFormat** key to be like this:

```
logFormat:  "%h %l %u [%t] '%r' %s %b '%i{Referer}' '%i{User-Agent}'"
```

Also found out that Logback project usess [PatternLayout](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/access/PatternLayout.html) class and got this output (as starting lines and other lines are **as usual**) in terminal:

```
09:27:33,944 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
09:27:33,944 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
09:27:33,944 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]
09:27:33,966 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.BasicConfigurator@316a598d - Setting up default configuration.
09:27:36,978 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@216914 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
09:27:37,008 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@216914 - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[com.nikolas.master_thesis] onto the JUL framework
09:27:37,010 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file-appender] - Setting bufferSize to [8 KB]
09:27:37,027 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1805845895 - No compression will be used
09:27:37,028 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy@1805845895 - Will use the pattern /home/nikola/Documents/DWApp-LOGs/DW-Bookshop_LOG-%d.log for the active file
09:27:37,050 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/home/nikola/Documents/DWApp-LOGs/DW-Bookshop_LOG-%d.log'.
09:27:37,050 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Roll-over at midnight.
09:27:37,068 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.DefaultTimeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy - Setting initial period to Thu Aug 13 09:27:06 CEST 2020
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [h]
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - [h] is not a valid conversion word
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [l]
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - [l] is not a valid conversion word
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [u]
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - [u] is not a valid conversion word
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [s]
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - [s] is not a valid conversion word
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [b]
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - [b] is not a valid conversion word
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [i]
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - [i] is not a valid conversion word
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - There is no conversion class registered for conversion word [i]
09:27:37,071 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.pattern.parser.Compiler@35764bef - [i] is not a valid conversion word
09:27:37,074 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file-appender] - Active log file name: /home/nikola/Documents/DWApp-LOGs/DW-Bookshop_LOG.log
09:27:37,074 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[file-appender] - File property is set to [/home/nikola/Documents/DWApp-LOGs/DW-Bookshop_LOG.log]
09:27:37,075 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[async-file-appender] - Attaching appender named [file-appender] to AsyncAppender.
09:27:37,076 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[async-file-appender] - Setting discardingThreshold to 0
09:27:37,077 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[async-console-appender] - Attaching appender named [console-appender] to AsyncAppender.
09:27:37,077 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[async-console-appender] - Setting discardingThreshold to 0
```

Apperantly I need to create **logback.xml** file as this line states:

```
09:27:33,944 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]
```

Any idea where does that logback.xml file needs to located in MAven project and which value for **logFormat** should I use then?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `>` sign from the log formats?

Comment: No, then it complains about `{` sign.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that you need to verify that `String.format(...)` can handle your custom format. But if it doesn't work even with the pattern for console output it's most probably something else like missing write access for the file or so.

Comment: @philonous: I guess you are right, but it seems that it's (**logFormat**) placeholders are not being utilized as they should. I've updated my question, so please take a look.

Comment: A `logback.xml` file is normally located under `src/main/resources`

Comment: @philonous: What's interesting I've already placed it there and it still get that INFO message `Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]`. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

To log http requests in a file you have to set `server: requestLog:` config. `logging` config is used for configurate logs from your application.

Look the documentation for that config and logback-access and logback-access-pattern references at:
https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/configuration.html#request-log

This is my example:

```
...
logging:
  level: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: file
      currentLogFilename: /logs/api.log
      archivedLogFilenamePattern: /logs/api-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz
      archivedFileCount: 7
      queueSize: 2048
  loggers:
    com.mstn: DEBUG
server:
    applicationConnectors:
      - type: http
        port: 8003
    adminConnectors:
      - type: http
        port: 9003
    requestLog:
      appenders:
        - type: file
          currentLogFilename: /logs/api-requests.log
          archivedLogFilenamePattern: /logs/api-requests-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz
          archivedFileCount: 7
          queueSize: 2048
database:
...
```